# ESRI JS API hosted locally but requests still go to https://js.arcgis.com?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, iis

In my current project we have hosted the ESRI JS API within the organisation's IIS.

For most of the part the deployed application works fine, but we notice that certain calls are being made to https://js.arcgis.com despite the corresponding JS files being present in the local deployment.

I have deployed the ESRI API as per instructions within their readme/install documentation. I have not completed the steps under *"Change the ArcGIS Services Directory "View In JavaScript" URL"* section, as I think these are optional and only apply when viewing the deployed map services from within the REST services directory.

Any ideas why the external calls are being made?

[image]

Comment: Is the "deployed application" your own custom built app? Or something provided by esri or someone else?

Comment: This is a custom GIS application utilizing ESRI's JS API

Answer (score 3):

Okay...so I eventually figured out why it was behaving like that.

Apparently, the URL changes had not been done one the particular instance and it was reading the original copy deployed within the 'js' folder and not the locally deployed one.

When we began the development, we were not using the locally deployed ESR JS API, and later in the development phase we switched to it. The setting for some reason remained unmodified for this environment.